# Stack around the variable 's' was corrupted

Tags: c, memory-corruption

I got this error in my rc4 algorithm, it works well, but i got this error every time when the message is too big, like 1000kB, here is the code:

```
char* rc4(const int* key, int key_size, char* buff, int buff_size){
int i, j, k;
int s[255], rk[255];    //rk = random_key
char* encrypted = alloc_char_buffer(buff_size);

for (i = 0; i < 255; i++){
    s[i] = i;
    rk[i] = key[i%key_size];
}


j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 255; i++){
    j = (j + s[j] + rk[i]) % 256;
    SWITCH(s + i, s + j);
}

i = 0;
j = 0;

for (k = 0; k < buff_size; k++){
    i = (i + 1) % 256;
    j = (j + s[i]) % 256;
    SWITCH(s + i, s + j);

    //try{

    //}
    //catch ()
    encrypted[k] = (char)(s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256] ^ (int)buff[k]);
}

encrypted[buff_size] = 0;

return encrypted;
}
```

at the end o the last loop i got this error, i think this is some type of buffer overflow error, the only variable able to do that is the 'encrypted' but at the end of the loop, the value of the variable 'k' have the exactly same value of 'buff_size' that is used to alloc memory for 'encrypted', if someone can help i'll thank you

the 'encrypted' is "non-null terminated", so if the string have 10 bytes i will allocate only 10 bytes, not 11 for the '\0'

if you need, here is the code for alloc_char_buffer(unsigned int)

```
char* alloc_char_buffer(unsigned int size){

char* buff = NULL;

buff = (char*)calloc(size+1, sizeof(char));

if (!buff)
    _error("program fail to alloc memory.");

return buff;
}
```

SWITCH:

```
//inversão de valores
void SWITCH(int *a, int *b){
*(a) = *(a) ^ *(b); //a random number
*(b) = *(a) ^ *(b); //get a
*(a) = *(a) ^ *(b); //get b
}
```

Comment: The `if (buff) free(buff);` in `alloc_char_buffer()` is redundant. Also, you could use `buff = calloc(size, sizeof(char));` to replace malloc-and-memset.

Comment: What does `SWITCH` do?

Comment: o yeah, thank for it, the redundant code is from the old method i was using where i needed pass a pointer to the function :s(but still not working :()

Comment: Pretty sure your boxes need to be 256 elements big, not 255 elements...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* encrypted = alloc_char_buffer(buff_size);
/* ... */
encrypted[buff_size] = 10;
```

Here is the problem. You allocate `buff_size` elements. Thus, the last valid index is `buff_size-1`, not `buff_size`.

Another issue:

```
j = (j + s[j] + rk[i]) % 256;
```

Thus the range of `j` is [0, 255], but the legal index of `s` is only [0, 254]. You should either declare `s` as a 256-element array or review the algorithm implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your following line is creating the problem as you are trying to access beyond your allocated memory.

```
encrypted[buff_size] = 10;
```

Additionally, you should avoid use ***calloc*** instead of writing your own function *alloc_char_buffer*. It would allocate memory and initialize with 0.

```
calloc(buff_size, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: sorry for that, it is just a test that i was doing just to test if the 'encrypted' was the cause of the problem, but the 's' variable still the same after that, only on the final loop she got the values changed.

Comment: I did it: change malloc for calloc but the problem persists

Comment: @user2542813: I still see that your program has encrypted[buff_size] = 10; encrypted[buff_size] = 0; in your code. you either allocate one more in calloc like buff_size+1 or use encrypted[buff_size -1] = 10;

Comment: the value in 'buff_size' is exactly what i need, this is the number of bytes contained on some file, so if the file have 5 characters on it(5 bytes)  'buff_size' must be initialized with 5 and then i'll allocate a buffer(char type) with only 5 bytes, so 'k' go from 0 to 4 iterating on all the bytes of the message.

Comment: @user2542813: yes you are correct, but in order to put '\0'(in the last statement in your function), you need to allocate extra as calloc(buff_size+1, sizeof(char)) and it should be fine.

Comment: hmm, i tried it and still not working ¬¬, in fact my intention is to ommit the '\0'